# Julia os type of package or library?

Tags: julia, ijulia-notebook

I am new to Julia, and beginning to port some machine learning projects over to Julia.  One thing I am missing is the python `os` library which can walk a directory path quite easily.  I am googling around and looks like it doesn't exist in Julia yet.. but wanted to throw up a question before I start writing my own implementation

for context here's the python function I'm porting

```py
import os
import fnmatch

def list_all_files(directory, extensions=None):
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory):
        for filename in filenames:
            base, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
            joined = os.path.join(root, filename)
            if extensions is None or ext.lower() in extensions:
                yield joined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [walkdir](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/file/#Base.Filesystem.walkdir). You can also use `readdir()`, maybe in combination with `filter()`.

Example:

```
for d in filter(isdir, readdir())
    println("I'm a directory: ", d)
end
```